# Centered div that doesn't stick to the edge but is able to resize with content

Tags: css, html

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
I have a centered lay out with a sidebar on the right and a container wrapping the sidebar and the content.
The container however has a grungy look and the borders extend out. The content is 960px and the backdrop for the content is 1200px.
When I center it using the normal margin-right/left auto method it is centered but when someone with a browser smaller than 1200px visits the site it will be pushed off to the side.

Since the content in the page will be dynamic using an absolute div for this would not give me the result I'm looking for since it won't resize if there is more content inside of it.

Any solutions to this issue or am I going to have to get my hands dirty in javascript?

Link to an example: http://duedate.wordtgetest.be/TEMP_LAYOUT/

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. `"When I center it using the normal margin-right/left auto method it is centered but when someone with a browser smaller than 1200px visits the site it will be pushed off to the side."` - what do you want to happen instead? Should it resize from `960px` to less than `960px`? Consider posting the entire relevant code you have so far.

Comment: I want it to cut off the borders up intil 960px and than start pushing it off to the side. I'll edit main post with some metacode to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Where is the code for your sidebar? - Can you give us the whole pages HTML and CSS please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's an option:
Place the image you're currently using in the 1200px wrapper in the body-Tag and use 
`background-position:top center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;`
and just remove the wrapper

```
body {
  background-image:url(bigBackdrop.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-position:top center;
}

#content{
  width: 960px
  margin:0px auto;
  background-image:url(bigBackdrop.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-position:top center;
}
```

That should to the trick.

Here's what you want to achieve:
http://www.fabsn.de/trash/stackoverflow/ThomasVanNuffel/index.htm

Comment: This will keep the image centered even when the browser resizes width to anything lower than 960 while the content will stick to the edge.

Comment: Okay sorry bout that, I forgot to add: You have to add the same background-image to the 960px wide element - also centered.

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue, I still have pretty big scrollbars from the header but i'll get rid of those using javascript :)

Comment: An other issues popped up, this will not work in IE6-7. Trying to fix it as we speak but it looks like IE doen't care about the body width at all.

Comment: Could you link an example or create a small one at www.jsfiddle.net for us? I create most of my websites that way and I haven't had this problem in any IE versions above 5.5.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.fabsn.de/trash/stackoverflow/ThomasVanNuffel/index.htm - it will now work in IE6 and above. The problem here is that you will need to move the content-wrapper down or change the images since there is now a visible line. And get rid of those crazy sidebar divs which you positioned absolute.

Comment: Thanks a bunch fabsn. Its so simple but we didn't think of it yesterday when trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't always need to use a container `div` to center content with a background. You can just as easily apply margins to the `body` element and use a centered image. Something perhaps like this:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  background-image: url(myimage.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: top;
}
```